# Convert mp4 file to byte array and string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, firebase-realtime-database, system.io.file

I working on project to upload files into firebase real-time database using firesharp in WinForm c#.

I searched a lot to understand how to do this.

I know about the option to write File.ReadAllBytes(), but I want to run the app on weak PC, with 4 GB ram, and he is very slow.
I succeeded to upload an image, it's work good.
I find something about Stram option, but I don't know how to do it with converting to String.

Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the file to binary, and the binary can be saved as arrays and strings.

```
//Read file to byte array

FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\path\to\your\file\here.txt");
byte[] fileBytes= new byte[stream.Length];

stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
//Begins the process of writing the byte array back to a file

using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\path\to\your\file\here.txt"))
{
   file.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
}
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/636646/Csharp-file-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-File

```
FileStream st = new FileStream(@"C:\2.jpg", FileMode.Open); 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[st.Length]; 
            st.Read(buffer, 0, (int)st.Length); 
            st.Close(); 
            Console.ReadLine();
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/648bd8b2-74ec-4054-9c68-68190b600971/how-to-convert-a-file-to-binary?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: The first code you wrote can work on any file? Not just pictures? And how to save the byte[] to String? Just add ToString()?

Comment: The code should work for any file.
And to convert byte[] to string, using `var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result); `

Comment: If my reply is helpful to you, please mark my reply as an Answer so that people with similar problems can solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: But how do I upload this as stram to firebase?